# I want to add a constraint to my table but an error keeps on showing

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id_product INT,
    name_prod VARCHAR2(100),
    category_prod VARCHAR2(255),
    Date_exp DATE,
    Qt_stock number,
    price INT ,
    CONSTRAINT prod PRIMARY KEY(id_product),
    CONSTRAINT c1 FOREIGN KEY(id_supp)REFERENCES supplier(id_supp)
)
**************************
CREATE TABLE supplier
(
  id_supp INT, 
  supp_name VARCHAR2(50),
  date_comm DATE,
  Address VARCHAR2(255),
  nombre_comm INT,
  CONSTRAINT supp PRIMARY KEY(id_supp)
)
```

the id_supp is a column and a primary key in table supplier
but

> invalid identifier

appears every time, how can I fix it?

Comment: which rdbms are you using ..sql server, mysql??

Comment: I am using toad

Comment: @Maryam Toad is a desktop application, not an RDBMS.

Comment: Why `SUPPLIER` (singular) but `PRODUCTS` (plural)? Why `name_prod` but `supp_name`? Should the names be NOT NULL and unique? Is it OK for a product to have no price?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes I know toad for oracle I meant.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create the `supplier` table first.

Then you can  refer to it as foreign key. And you need to add that column to your `products` table:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id_product INT,
    name_prod VARCHAR2(100),
    category_prod VARCHAR2(255),
    Date_exp DATE,
    Qt_stock number,
    price INT ,
    id_supp INT,
    CONSTRAINT prod PRIMARY KEY(id_product),
    CONSTRAINT c1 FOREIGN KEY(id_supp)REFERENCES supplier(id_supp)
)
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30c57/1)